# Ising Model in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, boolean

I'm writing a code in C++ for a 2D Ising model. Here's what the code should do:

1. Generate random NxN lattice, with each site either +1 or -1 value.
2. Select a site at random
3. If site when flipped (+1 to -1 or -1 to +1) is a state of lower energy, flip state ie. if dE < 0, flip state. If flipped state is of higher energy, flip with acceptance rate w = e^{-b(dE)}. Where dE is the change in energy if state is flipped.
   4.Do this for all NxN sites, without repetition. This is considered one sweep.
4. Do like 100 sweeps.

I'm having trouble with steps 1, 2 and 3, would appreciate any help! For step 1, I managed to create and display a lattice, but I can't seem to extract the value of a site at location (x, y). Steps 2 and 3, how do I use a boolean expression of some sort to flip according to acceptance probability?

```
 #include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
#include <iostream>
int main() //random generation of spin configuration
{
int L;              //Total number of spins L = NxN
int N = 30          //A square lattice of length 30
double B=1;         //magnetic field
double M;           //Total Magnetization = Sum Si
double E;           //Total Energy
int T = 1.0;
int nsweeps = 100;      //number of sweeps
int de;             //change in energy when flipped
double Boltzmann;       //Boltzmann factor
int x,y;            //randomly chosen lattice site
int i,j,a,c;            //counters
  int ROWS = 5;
  int COLS = 5;
  int matrix[ROWS][COLS];
  srand ( static_cast<unsigned> ( time ( 0 ) ) );
  for ( int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++ ) 
  {
    for ( int j = 0; j < COLS; j++ )
    {
      matrix[i][j] = rand () % 2 *2-1;
    }
  }

 // showing the matrix on the screen
    for(int i=0;i<ROWS;i++)  // loop 3 times for three lines
    {
        for(int j=0;j<COLS;j++)  // loop for the three elements on the line
        {
            cout<<matrix[i][j];  // display the current element out of the array
        }
    cout<<endl;  // when the inner loop is done, go to a new line
    }
    return 0;  // return 0 to the OS.

//boundary conditions and range
if(x<0) x += N;      
if(x>=L) x -= N;
if(y<0) y += N;
if(y>=L) y -= N;

//counting total energy of configuration
{  int neighbour = 0;    // nearest neighbour count

   for(int i=0; i<L; i++)
      for(int j=0; j<L; j++)
    {  if(spin(i,j)==spin(i+1, j))     // count from each spin to the right and above 
              neighbour++;
           else 
              neighbour--;
           if(spin(i, j)==spin(i, j+1))
              neighbour++;
           else
              neighbour--;
    }

    E = -J*neighbour - B*M;

//flipping spin
int x = int(srand48()*L);   //retrieves spin from randomly choosen site
int y = int(srand48()*L);

int delta_M = -2*spin(x, y);    //calculate change in Magnetization M
int delta_neighbour = spin(spinx-1, y) + spin(x+1, y)+ spin(x, y-1) + spin(x, y+1);
int delta_neighbour = -2*spin(x,y)* int delta_neighbour;

double delta_E = -J*delta_neighbour -B*delta_M;


//flip or not
if (delta_E<=0)
    {  (x, y) *= -1;     // flip spin and update values
           M += delta_M;
           E += delta_E;

        }



}
```

Comment: How do you measure the dE for a given flip?

Comment: Calculate the energy for the flipped state, subtract it with energy of the original state. 

The energy for any state at site = (product of neighbour states energy) + (magnetization*state at site)

Comment: This code is a mess and does not compile. Please give us missing functions/variabels like e.g. `spin`.

Comment: I'm really sorry about that - I'm trying my best to learn as I go, please bear with me!

I have updated the code, defining N and delta_neighbour and the section of the code- how do i make the expression "spin(x, y)" extract the value of that site at location (x, y)?

Each site can either take a value of +1 or -1 and is determined randomly at the start.

    
    int delta_neighbour = (spinx-1, y) + spin(x+1, y)+ spin(x, y-1) + spin(x, y+1);

    int delta_neighbour = -2*spin(x,y)* int delta_neighbour; //change in neighbour energy

Comment: There are too many issues with your code for a single answer. Try to build your program step by step. Use functions which perform one thing, and this they do well. Test each function individually and if necessary try to find out why it does not work. Then post specific questions again.

Comment: That is a very good idea. I think now the biggest trouble to start off with are these steps:

1. Generate NxN lattice with -1 or +1 at each site randomly.
2. How to extract the value at a site at location (x, y).

Do you think you can tell me what's wrong with these parts of the code for a start?

Comment: From your answer to my question about dE, it seems that energy is a per-site quantity, and that it somehow depends on the energy of the neighbouring sites -- but either you want to solve a gigantic simultaneous equation to decide all these energies to satisfy the equation you gave, or you mean that you want to "hold all other sites' energies fixed" while you update the current site's energy -- but in the latter case, the first term in your equation will cancel out when you do the subtraction!  Also what is magnetization?

Answer (score 1):

To follow up on my comment:

> There are too many issues with your code for a single answer. Try to
>   build your program step by step. Use functions which perform one
>   thing, and this they do well. Test each function individually and if
>   necessary try to find out why it does not work. Then post specific
>   questions again.

To get you started:

- Store your lattice as a `std::vector<int> lattice(N*N)`
- Access element `(x,y)` with `data[x+N*y]`.

Example:

```
#include <vector>

struct IsingModel
{ 
    unsigned size_;

    std::vector<int> lattice_;

    // access element (x,y)
    int& at(int x, int y) {
        return lattice_[x + y*size_];
    }
    int at(int x, int y) const {
        return lattice_[x + y*size_];
    }

    // generate size x size lattice
    IsingModel(unsigned size)
    : size_(size), lattice_(size*size, +1) {
    }

    static int BoolToSpin(bool v) {
        return v ? +1 : -1;
    }

    // initialize spin randomly
    void initializeRandom() {
        for(int y=0; y<size_; y++) {
            for(int x=0; x<size_; x++) {
                at(x,y) = BoolToSpin(rand()%2);
            }
        }
    }

    static int Energy(int a, int b) {
        return (a == b) ? +1 : -1;
    }

    // compute total energy
    unsigned computeTotalEnergy() const {
        unsigned energy = 0;
        for(int y=1; y<size_-1; y++) {
            for(int x=1; x<size_-1; x++) {
                energy += Energy(at(x,y), at(x+1,y));
                energy += Energy(at(x,y), at(x,y+1));
            }
        }
        return energy ;
    }

 };

 #include <iostream>     
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <ctime>

 int main() {
     srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(0))); // intialize random number generator
     IsingModel im(10);
     im.initializeRandom();
     unsigned energy = im.computeTotalEnergy();
     std::cout << energy << std::endl; // print energy
 }
```