# Generating NxN lattice and extracting the value of a site at location (x, y)

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm writing a portion of a code based on the Ising Model to do the following:

1. Generate a NxN lattice with either +1 or -1 at each site assigned at random
2. Extract the value of a site at location (x, y) using function spin (x, y)

I'm having trouble with part 2 - How do I make spin(x, y) return the value of the site at location (x, y)? For example how do I make "int H = 2* spin(x, y);" give H twice the value of the site at location (x, y)?

Part 1:

```
    //Generate NxN lattice with -1 or +1 at each site randomly.

const int LatSize = 5;
const int L = LatSize * LatSize;
int matrix[LatSize][LatSize];

int matrix[LatSize][LatSize];
srand ( static_cast<unsigned> ( time ( 0 ) ) );
for ( int i = 0; i < LatSize; i++ ) 
{
for ( int j = 0; j < LatSize; j++ )
{
matrix[i][j] = rand () % 2 *2-1;
}
}

//End of Generating matrix
```

Part 2:

```
    //Extracting value of a site at location (x,y)

int & spin (int x, int y); //extracting value of site at location (x, y)
int x = int(srand48()*LatSize); 
int y = int(srand48()*LatSize);

int delta_M = -2*spin(x, y); //change in magnetization energy

int delta_neighbour = spin(x-1, y) + spin(x+1, y)+ spin(x, y-1) + spin(x, y+1); 
delta_neighbour = -2*spin(x,y)* delta_neighbour; //change in neighbour product energy
```

Comment: Why two questions with same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22973658/ising-model-in-c

Comment: So either you're really tired, or you trying to figure out something than what you're asking. What's wrong with returning `matrix[x][y]` in spin? Do you need a pointer to that location (`matrix[x] + y`), so you can modify it? How does the Isis model affect this, (I'm no physicist).